# ttatcc gives dumb message: dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: macos, xquartz

Installed OracleSecureGlobalDesktopClient.dmg and when I went to run it, got this error:

```
a-taylor-ltm:bin a.taylor$ /Applications/Oracle\ Secure\ Global\ Desktop\ Client/5.10.923/Oracle\ Secure\ Global\ Desktop\ Client.app/Contents/MacOS/ttatcc
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libXpm.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/Oracle Secure Global Desktop Client/5.10.923/Oracle Secure Global Desktop Client.app/Contents/MacOS/ttatcc
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstalling Quartz (just run the upgrade, no need to uninstall) should solve this.  Download and install here.
http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/

Source: I tried it, and https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6616720

Comment: while we're at it, the next step to using ttatcc is to actually launch Quartz and have DISPLAY variable set.  in my ~/.profile i set it like this:  export DISPLAY=:0.0